# changes in Master page not inherited in subsites

Tags: 2013, master-page, site-logo

I have changed the logo in seattle.html in SharePoint designer so that it uses SharePoint:SPLinkButton instead of SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink and modified it to point to the root site collection. It works on the Site Collection, however when I create subsites the logo still points to the subsite it self. I opened the master page of the subsite I see that it still contains SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink not SharePoint:SPLinkButton.

Comment: Publishing feature will allow you to force subsites to inherit Master Page from parent site.. But there are few consequences of using Publishing feature..

Comment: No I am not allowed to activate publishing feature. thanks

Comment: What is the consequences of using the publishing feature?

Comment: For me it would be nice and easy but it has been decided.

Comment: I am currently doing the same thing as you and was planning to use the publishing feature on my team sites to inherit but now i need to reconsider..

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use Publishing feature, you need to either update the master page on each Team (sub)site you create or create a Feature that sets the master page of the subsite to be same as at the root site. You can use e.g., feature stapling to automatically run that feature always when subsite is created.

Comment: What would be a reason to not use publishing feature in a team site?

Comment: @user19952 please see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61325/are-there-any-problems-with-enabling-publishing-features-on-a-team-site, the most important problem is that you lose "Save site as template" option..