# Hide a navigation link from users that are not within a security group

Tags: 2013, development, permissions, navigation, team-sites

I am working on a Team site inside SharePoint 2013. and i have created a new navigation link as follow, named "Business Risks". but my question if there is a way to hide this link if the user are not inside the "Team Site Manager" security group ? i do not know why when i access the site settings i can not find an area for "Site Navigation" ?
Thanks
[image]

**EDIT**
This what i will get, when i click on save.although i can search for this group inside the group picker ,, very strange.. :-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a problem with the compilation of the Audiences. SharePoint does compile the audience on a regular basis. Maybe you need to trigger it manually in your environment or one of the jobs is hanging?

> **To compile an audience**:
>
> 1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials:
>
>    - You are a member of the Farm Administrators group.
> 2. In the Central Administration Web site, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
> 3. On the Service Applications page, in the list of service applications, click the User Profile Service Application link that you want to configure.
> 4. On the Manage Profile Service page, in the People section, click Compile Audiences.

Have a look at this [reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263278%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If this don't work have a look at the SharePoint Server Log (ULS Logs) on the frontend servers (or ask your admin if you are not).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Publishing feature for setting up security trimmed navigation links:

To get navigation setting you should enable Publishing feature on site collection and then site. You can do this by opening the Features page of Site Collection and then Site.

Once this is done, under Look and Feel you can see Navigation.

As you add Navigation nodes you can mention which Group/Users has permission.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/customize-the-navigation-on-your-team-site-HA103532378.aspx

Comment: thanks , but if i enable this will it affect any sections inside my site collection. i mean is there any side effects of enabling Publishing feature ?

Comment: No, Publishing feature is there to provide you with extra features to site collection, this feature is activated by default for Publishing side. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61325/are-there-any-problems-with-enabling-publishing-features-on-a-team-site

Comment: ok i enable the Publishing feature, and now i can see Navigation section under look & feel. and i edit the "Business Risk" link and i specify the "Team site Manager" as the link audience, but it showed a red line under it , with the following message "No exact match was found. Click the item(s) that did not resolve for more options."

Comment: You can click on the address book icon, then select "SharePoint Groups" from the dropdown and search for the group.

Comment: yes i can search for the group and it is there, but when i want to save the edit , i will get the following error:-"No exact match was found. Click the item(s) that did not resolve for more options."

Comment: @johnG which browser you are using.. Try to change your browser and see if you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: can you chekc my edit, i provide an image of the error ,, and yes i tried different browsers but all will have the same issue..

Comment: Try insert an existing group (site Members or Owners) to see if the issue is with the created group or with the audience trimming.

Comment: this problem will happen even with the default groups also.Very strange as i can search for the groups , but when i try to save  it will raise an error...