# How to make sure that on the main page of the "main" site, links to the "subsidiary" site were visible only to those who have permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

How to make sure that on the main page of the "main" site, links to the "subsidiary" site were visible only to those who have permissions?

Related Articles:

1. [site navigation links only visible to those with permissions](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ae471af3-bf1c-4e37-a3fb-4b48c609c523/site-navigation-links-only-visible-to-those-with-permissions?).
2. [Target files, news and pages to specific audiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/target-files-news-and-pages-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293).
3. [Hide a navigation link from users that are not within a security group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121575/hide-a-navigation-link-from-users-that-are-not-within-a-security-group).

This did not help in solving the problem.

Even if you enable audience targeting on the main page of site 2. Being on the main page of the "main" site, a user who is not in the audience of the site 2 does not lose links to the "subsidiary" site.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The audience targeting need to be configured in the 'main' site Navigation settings when add the link to quick launch.

Besides, you can also use code to hide the link who doesn't have proper permission.

Here is a article for your reference:
[How to hide links in the navigation from users that don't have edit permissions for certain pages in SharePoint 2013](http://sharingtothepoint.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-hide-links-in-navigation-from.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.